# Adding and toggling legend with layer in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, legend

I'm currently trying to add a legend to my map and to show/hide it, when the corresponding layer (an image layer) is shown/hidden.
My approach was to add a custom button with a .png of my legend. That worked without problems.

The image layer ("light") is deactivated when loading the map:

```
light.setVisibility(false);
```

Now, I want to show the legend when activating the layer and hide it when deactivating the layer and so on. And that works as well, but only once using these lines:

```
(function legend() {
    light.events.register("visibilitychanged", light, function() {
    if (light.getVisibility() === true) {
        map.addControl(button);
        } else {
        map.removeControl(button);
        }
    });  
}());
```

I guess i have to reload the function somehow after the button is removed?

All things I tried didn't work and that was the best I was able to come up with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the attribution feature of OpenLayers for this:

> http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/attribution.html

This will work accordingly (ie. active/deactivate) with every layer in your map. You'd only need to replace the text with your PNG:

```
'attribution': "<img src='mylegend.png'/>"
```

If you also need to change the position of your legend, you can play with the CSS properties to place it where you want.

Comment: While this will indeed work, it's nice to actually show the attribution too. (Heck, it's even [required](http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright) for most maps I know of.)