# Generating Dynamic Legend with OpenLayers and GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, legend

I am using OpenLayers 3 and GeoServer to create a map with multiple layers. I am able to generate legend for each layer from GeoServer using  GetLegendGraphic and display them using the following:

```
<div>
 <img src="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=12&HEIGHT=12&LAYER=country:Layer1">
</div>
```

I tried to control the legend visibility based on the visibility of its corresponding layer. I searched various sources and found [How to add a legend and toggle the legend with a layer in Openlayers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83300) which did not work for my case.

Now I have the following problem:

When a Map layer is made invisible, the legend is still displayed. How, can I control the legend visibility dynamic i.e. make the legend visible only when its corresponding layer is selected and make the legend invisible when its corresponding layer is invisible.

Is there a working example?

Comment: you just hide the legend image for that layer when you make the layer invisible

Comment: Yes, do you have any examples or some links to relevant examples.

Comment: Nope, that is just basic css/js stuff https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=hide+image+with+javascript

Comment: Thank You.
To monitor the Layer selection event and hide/show legend image:
LayerID.on('change:visible', function(){   
   // javascript code to hide/show legend image
  });